# Facebook granting rights even after refusing

Tags: ios, facebook, authorization

I've got an application that enables the user to publish on his wall.
To do so, he clicks on a button that will ask him to login via a webview if he's not logged in already.
Then, he'll be asked to accept the application ( and thus to give his basic informations ), and right after that, the publishing rights (publish_stream).

Here comes the problem :

- If I authorize the application to publish in my name, I get the authorization. Which is normal.
- But if I don't accept it, the application still gets the authorization and is able to publish on the user's wall.

For information, I use : `OpenActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:`

in the

`openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:`

and check the authorization with

`[FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] != NSNotFound`

So my question is : **Why are the rights granted even though I refused them ?**

---

**EDIT :** [Bug fixed](https://developers.facebook.com/x/bugs/510659758953661/)

Comment: Have you logged onto the Facebook website and de-authorised the app from there? If you haven't done that then Facebook will still grant rights until you do.